# How to implement the work of several bots on one server?

Tags: python, heroku, telegram-bot

I create a bot that gives other bots ready-made features! I thought up and wrote a shit code, it seems earned, and after in the main bot gave an error: Traceback (most recent call last):
How to fix and is there any other way of performing this task, and in General how to remove the bad code???

bot.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import sqlite3
import mini_bot

from telebot import types

from config import main_token

bot = telebot.TeleBot(main_token) # Bot init webhook

@bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) # Start
def start_message(message):
    key = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() # Keyboard 'Go'
    go_btn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Начнем", callback_data="go_action")
    key.add(go_btn)
    text = '*Я помогаю контролировать сотрудников через чаты.*\n\nНапоминаю нужным людям в нужное время, что им нужно делать. Попробуй меня и напиши @alantsoff обо мне отзыв.'
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=key)

@bot.callback_query_handler(func=lambda c:True)
def btn_action(c):
    if c.data == 'go_action':
        text = '1. Перейдите в бот @BotFather и создайте нового бота.\n\n2. После создания бота вы получите токен бота (выглядит вот так - 123456:ABC-DEF1234gh...) - скопируйте его и скиньте сюда.'
        msg = bot.send_message(c.message.chat.id, text, parse_mode="Markdown")
        bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, save_token)
    elif c.data == 'no_ref':
        create_bot(c.message)

def save_token(message):
    global token
    token = message.text
    sql_query = 'INSERT INTO `Pushist_Tokens` (`id`, `token`) VALUES (NULL, "' + token + '")'
    conn = sqlite3.connect('Chinook_Sqlite.sqlite')
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute(sql_query)
    conn.close()
    key = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() # Keyboard 'Go'
    no_ref = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Нет реферала", callback_data="no_ref")
    key.add(no_ref)
    text = 'Пришлите @username человека, от которого вы узнали про меня.\n\n*Он и вы дополнительно получите по 1 месяцу расширенных функции после оплаты.*'
    msg = bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=key)
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, create_bot)

def create_bot(message):
    mini_bot.start(token)
    bot.send_message(message.chat.id, 'Всё готово! Проверьте бота')

bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)
```

mini_bot.py

```py
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import telebot
import sqlite3

from telebot import types

def start(token):
    global bot
    bot = telebot.TeleBot(token) # Bot init webhook

    @bot.message_handler(commands=['start']) # Start
    def sm(message):
        start_message(message)

    @bot.message_handler(content_types=["new_chat_members"]) # New member
    def nm(message):
        new_mbr(message)

    bot.polling(none_stop=True, interval=0)

def new_mbr(message):
    if message.chat.type == "group" or message.chat.type == "supergroup":
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, str(message.chat.id))

def start_message(message):
    if message.chat.type == "private":
        key = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardMarkup() # Keyboard 'Go'
        del_btn = telebot.types.InlineKeyboardButton(text="Удалить запрос", callback_data="del_request")
        key.add(del_btn)
        text = '*Добавь новые запросы!*\n\nНе забудь убедиться, что я есть в чатах, в которые ты хочешь добавить запросы.\n\nЕсли захочешь удалить существующий запрос, используй /delete или кнопку внизу. Если передумал и хочешь начать заново, напиши /new\n\nЧаты для добавления:'
        bot.send_message(message.chat.id, text, parse_mode="Markdown", reply_markup=key)
```

Error:

> 2019-08-06T10:20:08.096147+00:00 app[bot.1]: 2019-08-06 10:20:08,095 (util.py:65 PollingThread) ERROR - TeleBot: "ApiException occurred, args=('A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:\n[b\'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}\']',)
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096261+00:00 app[bot.1]: Traceback (most recent call last):
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096266+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/util.py", line 59, in run
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096269+00:00 app[bot.1]:     task(*args, **kwargs)
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096277+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/**init**.py", line 276, in **retrieve_updates
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096279+00:00 app[bot.1]:     updates = self.get_updates(offset=(self.last_update_id + 1), timeout=timeout)
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096281+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/__init**.py", line 246, in get_updates
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096283+00:00 app[bot.1]:     json_updates = apihelper.get_updates(self.token, offset, limit, timeout, allowed_updates)
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096285+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 180, in get_updates
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096288+00:00 app[bot.1]:     return _make_request(token, method_url, params=payload)
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096290+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 56, in _make_request
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096292+00:00 app[bot.1]:     return _check_result(method_name, result)['result']
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096294+00:00 app[bot.1]:   File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/telebot/apihelper.py", line 75, in _check_result
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096296+00:00 app[bot.1]:     raise ApiException(msg, method_name, result)
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096299+00:00 app[bot.1]: telebot.apihelper.ApiException: A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096303+00:00 app[bot.1]: [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}']
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096307+00:00 app[bot.1]: "
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096478+00:00 app[bot.1]: 2019-08-06 10:20:08,096 (**init**.py:417 WorkerThread2) ERROR - TeleBot: "A request to the Telegram API was unsuccessful. The server returned HTTP 409 Conflict. Response body:
>   2019-08-06T10:20:08.096481+00:00 app[bot.1]: [b'{"ok":false,"error_code":409,"description":"Conflict: terminated by other getUpdates request; make sure that only one bot instance is running"}']"

Answer (score 0):

Use WebHooks.
This method is much easier.
The telebot module is not asynchronous nor threaded. Is is fully synchronous and do bot.polling() in this your thread blocking it.
Using webhooks with async http server like aiohttp you can get multitoken async application. Goole the example.